# ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: this is MySQLdb version (1, 2, 5, 'final', 1), but _mysql is version (1, 2, 4, 'beta', 4)?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am trying to deploy a Django sample project with Google App Engine. It's throwing the error mentioned in the question title.
Locally the app running well. In requirements.txt I changed the mysql-python version to 1.2.4 and 1.2.5 both didn't work. I am getting 500 Error.
I checked many answers to this same question on SO but nothing seems to be working.
My app.yaml

```
# [START django_app]
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/
- url: .*
  script: mysite.wsgi.application

# Only pure Python libraries can be vendored
# Python libraries that use C extensions can
# only be included if they are libraries available
# as part of the AppEngine SDk
libraries:
- name: MySQLdb
  version: "latest"
# [END django_app]
```

My appengine_config:

```
# [START vendor]
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
vendor.add('lib')
# [END vendor]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.2.4b4 is indeed, at the time of this writing, the latest MySQLdb version that app engine supplies in production. You give no details about your setup, but if you're installing in a virtual environment from that requirements.txt, it's quite possible that a MySQLdb.py file be among the Python files you're uploading to GAE production: make sure to *not* do that, so that `import MySQLdb` will get the version supplied by GAE itself (with the appropriate specification in your app.yaml, of course).

Locally, develop with 1.2.4, to avoid accidentally using 1.2.5 features that 1.2.4 does not provide; but, most important, **don't** end up with a `MySQLdb.py` file in the directory tree you upload to app engine.

If you provide the relevant details of your app.yaml and of the directory tree that you're uploading, you may make it possible for us to supply more, and more specific, help and information. Based on the very scant info you chose to provide in your question, this is the best we can do, so far.

Comment: Removed the Mysql-python folder from the code I was uploading to GAE. It worked.